# "Configuration system failed to initialize"

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-services

I have created a Windows Service and i am calling a web service method from my windows service.

When i run my windows service, i am getting this error:

```
"Configuration system failed to initialize"
```

**Note**: The services are installed and my web service is running from Visual Studio (ASP.NET development server)

Please help to fix this error.

Comment: This is to due to a problem in initializing your .config file of your win service. Can you paste it here for reference

Comment: invalid xml in your config file?

Comment: I, too, have been having this problem, FYI, ever since the Fall Creator's update.